# How to implement searcher within kendo-multiselect

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

please help me to implement searcher within kendo-multiselect.

How my code look now:-

```html
          <div class="col-auto px-2 mb-2">
            <span
              class="d-block font-size-regular pb-1">{{ 'invoice.downloadConfirmation.search.salesRep' | translate }}</span>
            <kendo-multiselect [data]="salesRepsDropDownData" [textField]="'repName'" [valueField]="'repId'"  [(ngModel)]='salesRepsSelected'
              [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            </kendo-multiselect>
          </div>
```

and my output look like :-
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spyiq.png

my expectation output:-
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GupJW.png

please help me on it. if there more information need please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo offers filter option

```
 <div class="example-wrapper">
        <kendo-multiselect
                #list
                [data]="data"
                [filterable]="true"
                textField="text"
                valueField="value"
                placeholder="T-shirt size"
            >
        </kendo-multiselect>
    </div>
```